# Subscription to UnicastProcessor never triggers

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I wish to batch and process items as they come along so i created a UnicastProcessor and subscribed to it like this

```
UnicastProcessor<String> processor = UnicastProcessor.create()

processor
        .bufferTimeout(10, Duration.ofMillis(500))
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                System.out.println("OnSubscribe");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<String> strings) {
                System.out.println("OnNext");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("OnError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("OnComplete");
            }
        });
```

And then for testing purposes i created a new thread and started adding items in a loop

```
new Thread(() -> {
    int limit = 100
    i = 0
    while(i < limit) {
        ++i
        processor.sink().next("Hello $i")
    }
    System.out.println("Published all")
}).start()
```

After running this (and letting the main thread sleep for 5 seconds) i can see that all item have been published, but the subscriber does not trigger on any of the events so i can't process any of the published items.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

## Reactive Streams specification is the answer!

> The total number of onNext´s signalled by a Publisher to a Subscriber
>   MUST be less than or equal to the total number of elements requested
>   by that Subscriber´s Subscription at all times. [[Rule 1.1]](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.2/README.md#1.1)

In your example, you just simply provide a subscriber who does nothing in any sense. In turn, Reactive Streams specification, directly says that nothing will happen (there will be no onNext invocation) if you have not called `Subscription#request` method

> A Subscriber MUST signal demand via Subscription.request(long n) to
>   receive onNext signals. [[Rule 2.1]](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.2/README.md#2.1)

Thus, to fix your problem, one of the possible solutions is changing the code in the following way:

```
UnicastProcessor<String> processor = UnicastProcessor.create()

processor
    .bufferTimeout(10, Duration.ofMillis(500))
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
            System.out.println("OnSubscribe");
            subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<String> strings) {
            System.out.println("OnNext");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println("OnError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("OnComplete");
        }
    });
```

Note, in this example demand in size `Long.MAX_VALUE` means an unbounded demand so that all messages will be directly pushed to the given `Subscriber` [[Rule 3.17]](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.2/README.md#3.17)

### Use UnicatProcessor correctly

On the one hand, your example will work correctly with mentioned fixes. However, on the other hand, each invocation of `FluxProcessor#sink()` (yeah sink is `FluxProcessor`'s method) will lead to a redundant calling of `UnicastProcessor`'s `onSubscribe` method, which under the hood cause a few atomic reads and writes which might be avoided if create `FluxSink` once and safely use it as many tame as needed. For example:

```
UnicastProcessor<String> processor = UnicastProcessor.create()
FluxSink<String> sink = processor.serialize().sink();
...
new Thread(() -> {
    int limit = 100
    i = 0
    while(i < limit) {
        ++i
        sink.next("Hello $i")
    }
    System.out.println("Published all")
}).start()
```

Note, in this example, I executed an additional method `serialize` which provide thread-safe sink and ensure that the calling of `FluxSink#next` concurrently will not cause a violation of the ReactiveStreams spec.

Comment: Another issue: you should also call `sink()` only once and reuse the provided `FluxSink` rather than calling it in a loop.

Comment: @SimonBaslé, technically it is possible because `UnicastProcessor` provides internal synchronization in case of default queue, but yeah. Will mention that